# Android SDK: Development reference device to test

Tags: android

**Note: There were similar questions about this topic but were old threads. Also please note that this question is a development related question but not a personal mobie phone advice**

I will start android development so planning to buy an android mobile device **only** to test my apps and work on it. I saw that at the moment there mainly HTC, Motorola, Samsung and SonyErricson android supported devices on the market.

Which of these brands do you think I should have as a development device? Or as a reference device? for example maybe the current Android emulators are close to HTC phones and a Samsung should be nice to test because it is different in screen size or by some SDK's? or it does't really matter cause other than the screen sizes I will always get the same results.

note: I live in europe

Comment: @closevoter please explain why this question is marked as off-topic and not related with software development in anyway? and where this question can be better asked if not in a developer forum? in ebay, amazon? some guys here really need some better hobbies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a [Nexus S](http://www.google.com/nexus) or it's upcoming successor the Nexus Prime (or whatever it's going to be called). They're easily unlocked for root access and are the purest breed of Android, without any of the vendor modifications like HTC Sense or Samsung Touch Wiz.

If you're seriously into testing, you won't get around to having multiple devices, preferably at least one model for each major vendor (mainly HTC, Samsung); might also get a tablet. Many of the obvious compatibility problems can be found using the emulator, though -- so do test in there a lot.

Comment: tnx, I will check that one in store. What do you think about htc desire or samsung galaxy since they can be easily found

Comment: The Desire and Galaxy are rather old, in that direction I'd suggest a Desire HD or Galaxy S2.

Comment: tnx what do you mean by old? OS version or cpu and memory wise? if latter I would prefer a low tech device for testing

Comment: Both the Desire and Galaxy S are high-end devices from mid-2010 with powerful CPU, spacious memory and high-resolution 480x800 screens. If you want a lower-spec device take a look at a Galaxy Ace (medium-end, 320x480) or a HTC Wildfire (240x320, low-end).

Comment: I just call them old because the current generation has mostly dual-cores CPU and even more RAM (the Nexus S mentioned above has a fast but single core).

Answer (score 2):

My opinion you can choose whatever you want. More "professional" probably is "Nexus One" from Google. I personally use HTC Wildfire S a and I'm missing it for all purposes. What screen size, version of Android or brand theme style - SDK support all sizes of screen (you personally can change it), Samsung, Sony Ericsson, LG and other companies has release add-on that user can use the native brand interface.

By the way first 3 monthes I've developed only using an emulator without device.

Comment: tnx can you edit your answer to be a bit more clear? What are you missing in which device? you can personally chgange parameters where? in emuletors? How is wildfire?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was a little vague sense outlined. Let's start in order:
1. What is miss in which device? You know, basic differences can not be. When choosing a device guided by the following: a more recent version of Android (I have 2.3.3 for mobile devices), the device must have a complete set of services such as BlueTooth, Wi-Fi, built-in GPS, support SD memory cards, availability of photo camera is also desirable.
2. I am very glad that I had HTC, a device that has everything, and it solves any task. Fast, efficient device - debug programs on it is a pleasure.

Comment: 3. Before you start writing a program and test it, via SDK manager you create an AVD file - Android Virtual Device, where YOU specifies all the parameters of virtual device: version of android, device screen size, size of virtual SD-card, etc.
4. At any time you can change the parameters of the existing AVD
5. I recommend Eclipse IDE, it is easy to integrate with Android SDK
6. When you launch the program code for execution, emulator has run and load your previously created AVD

Comment: 7. If you buy a device, and connect it to PC via USB cable, then application will upload to device, and run well on the device

I believe that testing application on device is better and more useful) although at first time you can use an emulator.